# Using ffmpeg to cut videos with more precision than key frames allow

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

I'm trying to cut a video (a debate on TV) with FFmpeg without re-encoding, and I need to cut between 2 sentences a guy pronounce. I think the precise moment is between two keyframes, because whatever the timestamp I try to cut at, I always get too much sound (and video) or too few. Here is my ffmpeg command line :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 0:0:0.9 -vcodec copy -acodec copy videoB.mp4 -y
```

I'm aware that the position of the `-ss` option in the command line matters: here, it is supposed to give me all the accuracy FFmpeg can offer. I know I'm probably trying to cut my video neither on a I-frame, nor on P- or B-frames.

So is there a way to get the closest (P- or B-) frame, doing some calculations with the preceding I-frame to generate a new I-frame, then start the video with this brand new I-frame and no sound, until the correct timestamp is reached. Then the video could go on normally.

I really don't want to bother me with re-encoding (which is an use of FFmpeg I don't master on command line). I'm using FFmpeg version 2.5.8-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.

Thanks.

Comment: You only wish to re-encode the split GOPs - that's called smart rendering. AFAIK, that's tricky to do manually with ffmpeg. Try SolveigMM Video Splitter - http://www.videohelp.com/software/SolveigMM-Video-Splitter

Comment: Thanks but I'm under Linux. Any other tool which would be more suitable to my environment ?

Comment: Also SolveigMM video splitter seems to not be free anymore ;D

Comment: "without re-encoding". Not going to happen on any keyframe based file type, with any tool. Only possible on non-keyframe based files. Just re-encode with high fidelity. If you do this a lot, reconsider your workflow to include non-keyframe based files, or port directly from your source files to your end-user file with a single encode (difficult to create a workflow like that, but well worth it if you can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it simply, but here's a pretty good work around.

First, cut near the desired position (at keyframes) with stream copy and then re-encode the frame-exact part of the video. Let's say:

```
ffmpeg -ss 120 -t 40 -i input.mp4 -c copy -y temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -vcodec h264 -crf 21 -acodec mp3 -ss 1.080 -t 38.480 -y final.mp4
```

Thus, temp.mp4 starts *before* 120 sec and has a duration of *at least* 40 seconds
and final.mp4 has a duration of *exactly* 38.48 seconds.

When processing my home videos and stuff recorded from television, I use (-2s) for the desired start position and (+4s) for the duration. During re-encoding, I use milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

### No

There is no way to precisely cut a video with FFmpeg if you need to cut outside an I-frame without re-encoding.

You could try software that can handle "smart rendering", but I am not aware of any such software for Linux. On Windows, you could use "TMPGEnc MPEG Smart Renderer" or SolveigMM Video Splitter. The latter has serious performance issues. I highly recommend TMPGEnc, but it is not free.